# Intercept controllers

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, interceptor, castle-dynamicproxy

I am trying to create Audit logs for every controller so that I can keep track of invoked Actions. I am using .net core and Castle Core Dynamic Proxy.

```
class AuditInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly IAuditingHelper _auditingHelper;

    public AuditingInterceptor(IAuditingHelper auditingHelper)
    {
        _auditingHelper = auditingHelper;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
       invocation..Proceed();
       log.info(audit); // elided 
    }
}
```

How can I intercept every Controller ?  I can use Simple injector or Autofac.

The reason I am not interested in Filters is that I have 4500 actions. I dont want to decorate them all.

Comment: Do you need all of that (external libraries, etc)? Wouldn't a simple ASP.NET Core middle-ware work for such a simple task?

Comment: Essentially, I need Audits. In a middleware I can have access to Request and Response. But I need more structure. ie: Class name, method name, parameters. etc.

Comment: What about using IActionFilter?  ActionArguments gets you the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [action filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for this. You can retrieve useful information about the controller and action being executed from the `ActionDescriptor`. For example:

```
public class AuditAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
   {
       var actionDescriptor = (ControllerActionDescriptor)context.ActionDescriptor;
       var controllerName = actionDescriptor.ControllerName;
       var actionName = actionDescriptor.ActionName;
       var parameters = actionDescriptor.Parameters;
       var fullName = actionDescriptor.DisplayName;
   }
}
```

You can register the action filter using an attribute on controllers/actions:

```
[Audit]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
{
}
```

Or globally (every action) at application startup:

```
services.AddMvc(c => c.Filters.Add(new AuditAttribute()));
```

Comment: i have 4500 controller action. There is a reason I am asking for interceptor. My fault, you wouldnt know that.

Comment: this is not the answer I am looking for. I know what a filter is dear sir. I want interceptor.

Comment: @DarthVader I've explained how you can decorate each action using a global filter so you don't have to decorate them individually in my answer. Action filters are just a technical detail to implement the interception concept.

Comment: no they are not. they are decorator not interceptor.